# Validation on "January 01, 0001" date on a data (value is null)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem with my output where it has January 01, 0001. This detail explains that if the value is 0 or no data, supposedly the data column on the date is also 0 or not showing at all. I'm using MVC for this program.

**CONTROLLER**

```
 InventoryItemID = grouped.FirstOrDefault().invItem.InventoryItemId,
 QuantityRequest = grouped.Sum(a => (a.invItemj == null ? 0 : a.invItemj.Quantity)),
 Status = (grouped.FirstOrDefault().reqj == null) ? string.Empty : grouped.FirstOrDefault().reqj.Status,
 LastRequestedDate = (grouped.FirstOrDefault().reqj == null) ? default(DateTime) : grouped.Max(a => a.reqj.RequestDate)

 InventoryItemID = inv.InventoryItemId,
                          ItemName = inv.ItemName,
                          UnitOfDescription = uom.Description,
                          ItemCode = inv.ItemCode,
                          TotalStock = remainingQtyj == null ? 0 : 
 remainingQtyj.RemainingQuantity,
                          RequestedQuantity = requestedQtyj == null ? 0 : 
 requestedQtyj.QuantityRequest,
                          LastRequestedDate = 
 requestedQtyj.LastRequestedDate
```

**MODEL**

```
    public DateTime?  LastRequestedDate { get; set; }

    public string LastRequestedDateString => String.Format("{0: MMMM dd, yyyy}", LastRequestedDate);
```

This is the output of the column date:
[Stocks With Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp2aS.png)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check `LastRequestedDate.Value` is or isn't default datetime.

If `LastRequestedDate.Value` equal to `default(DateTime)` given it a empty `string`

```
  public string LastRequestedDateString => (LastRequestedDate.Value == default(DateTime)) ?
            string.Empty :
            LastRequestedDate.Value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Comment: It's my pleasure:).